# Locate the skipped rows in source file after using numpy genfromtxt python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

my is question about `genfromtxt` in python. I am using the following code :

```
syms = np.genfromtxt('final.csv', delimiter = ';', dtype=str, skip_header=1, invalid_raise=False)[:, 0:]
```

Due to the `invalid_raise` a number of rows is skipped. Is there any way to locate the skipped rows in the source file (csv) so to delete them from there as well? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may be a daft suggestion, but can't you just write the imported data back?

Comment: You mean save the `syms` as a new csv file (without the rows that were skipped)?

Comment: Yep, exactly. Could that work for you?

Comment: I assume so. I will try and let you know. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Usually rows are invalid because the number of columns differs.  You could read the file (`readlines`), then get the number of elements after a split for each line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it may need debugging):

```
with open('final.csv') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
lens = [len(line.split(';')) for line in lines]
# should give the length of each line
len1 = lens[1]   # the length of the first data line
errors = [i for i,n in enumerate(lens[1:] if n!=len1] 
# should give line number of lines with length different from len1
```

I don't have a good test file at hand, so won't try to test/debug this.  But the logic should be straight forward.